# How do you pronounce 盛开?

Tags: pronunciation

The phrase 盛开 means to bloom, as in, "池塘里的荷花盛开." Is this pronounced as "shèng kāi", or is it pronounced as "chéng kāi"?

Comment: "shèng kāi", of cource. Generally, different pronunciation of a character has a different meaning.

Comment: ＂四角号码新词典＂５３１０２ 盛（一）shèng  （１）兴旺，繁盛。例：繁荣昌盛 （２）强烈，旺盛。例：年轻气盛（３）隆重，规模大。例：盛会｜盛宴（４）丰富，华美。例：盛馔｜盛装。（５）深厚。例：盛意。（６）广泛。例：盛传。（７）姓（二）chéng（１）把东西放进器物里。例：盛饭。（２）容纳。例：这会场能盛一万人

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you pronounce it as "shèng kāi." The other pronunciation, "chéng" is for the phrase "盛饭."

Answer (score 2):

You can guess the pronunciation according to its usage:

```
"盛("chéng")" in 盛饭 is used as a verb, which means to fill or to contain.

"盛("shèng")" in 盛开 is used as a non-verb(adj./adv./noun), which means prosperous(ly), flourishing(ly)... (盛宴,盛装,旺盛,兴盛...)
```

by the way, 盛"shèng" is also used as a surname, such as [this man](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9B%9B%E5%85%89%E7%A5%96)

Answer (score 0):

"盛("shèng")" is not only in 盛开 but also same pronunciation in 盛大，盛宴，盛装，盛会。。。usually used to describe very large/important/formal/official occasions.

"盛("chéng")" is used mostly in phrase like 盛饭，盛菜，盛汤... means 'adding 饭/菜/汤 to a bowl or a pot'.